# Looping through paired list to merge rows of Data Frame in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

I have a data frame where all of the cells are string. I want to loop through a paired list and concatenate the rows of the data frame.

For example, I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df=[['7','4','5','',''],["","","",'7','4'],['9','4','7','8','4'],["","","",'7','5'],['4','8','5','4','6'],['4','9','41','74','20'],['4','Super','yes','0','9']]
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df.astype('str')
print(df)
0   1   2   3   4   
7   4   5           
            7   4
9   4   7   8   4
            7   5
4   8   5   4   6
4   9   41  74  20
```

I want to loop through the paired list below, where the first element is a start and a second end.

```
list_index=[[1,3],[4,5]]
```

This is my trial. I tried to change the list into range so that I can access each pared elements and loop through them, but no luck throwing `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

```
for row,index in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(list_index)):
        for j in range(list_index[i]):
            df[row,:] = df[row,:] + row
```

Finally, for the start and end of indices I have above, I want the data final data frame to look like the this:

```
0   1   2   3   4   
7   4   5           
9   4   7   787 445
44  89  541 474 620
```

I am not sure how to loop through a paired elements of list in python. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi I dont understand your output. So you want starting at row 1 column 3 `[1,3]` to row 4 column 5 `[4,5]` what to happen? Where are the empty cells of the original df in row 2? `[2,0:3]`

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your desired output. In particular, I think it should be 9, 4, 7, 787, 445. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ Björn B, Thanks for your reply. No, the columns are not affected at all. I want to concatenate the data frame rows starting from 1 to 3 and 4 to 5. The columns are not affected at all, I want to concatenate rows between 1 and 3 and 4 and 5 for all columns.

Comment: @Ramin Melikov thanks for spotting that. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is abother solution without the `groupby`

```
start_end = [[1,3],[4,5]]

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for l in start_end:

    temp_df = df.iloc[l[0] : l[1] + 1,:].apply(lambda x : ''.join(x)).to_frame().transpose()

    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, temp_df], ignore_index = True)

new_df
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you soo much. I understood how it works now. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
# this is an important step because we need a column to groupby
df['gb'] = 'gb'

start_end = [[1,3],[4,5]]

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for l in start_end:

    temp_df = df.iloc[l[0] : l[1] + 1,:].groupby(['gb']).agg(lambda x : ''.join(x)).reset_index(drop = True)

    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, temp_df], ignore_index = True)

new_df
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. I have been trying to figure this out the whole day. It's awesome, it would be great if you could explain how the lambda function is working here and also can I use the same logic for dynamic number of columns? For instance, what if the the number of columns are three or six next time?

Comment: I just updated the code. I removed a few things. Now, it can do this with any number of columns. It was late at night and I don't know what I was thinking, hard-coding all of the columns. The lambda function concatenates all of the grouped cells for each column. If you've worked with Oracle, it's like listagg, and in SQLite it's group_concat.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this. I am now trying to find an alternative method to solve this problem. Can you please help me solving this using for loop, if possible. I am trying to learn how to use for loop to achieve something like this in python. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: There is a for loop there. Did you not see that?